# Disable /Account/Register page after user is logged in - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Hi there,**

I'm searching for solution to disable opening the link /Account/Register, after the user is logged in. My knowledge about asp.net applications is still low and need to exercise.

The link is disabled in main page, but when I manually enter the link into the address bar like: http://example.com:23456/Account/Register I get actual registration with logged in user.

What I need to do is to check if there is logged in user before loading register page and redirect to homepage.

For many questions I have answered in this forum but now I need help..

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Page_Load` event you can check if user is logged in and redirect him if so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx"); //redirect to main page
    }
}
```

Note this is solution for ASP.NET. And `MVC` variant:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: @{
    
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/"); //redirect to main page
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

On the page_load event of registration check whether is already been registered with the application and if he is than redirect him to home page. You should write something like this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

if (!IsPostBack)
{
 if (MySessionHelper.UserInfo != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://example.com:23456/", false);
            }
}
}
```

Here  MySessionHelper.UserInfo  session object that holds the logged in/registered user info